# Android: close a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am looking for a method that closes a notification, but in such a way that if the app makes a new notification it would still be displayed

I was using a method where it closed the notification, for example from messenger, and after that messenger could not make any new notifications

Thanks on advance

Comment: We'll need to see some code around how you are creating the notifications. By default, Android allows Apps to create as many notifications as they like, so something else is wrong here.

Comment: I am nor creating a notification, I am listening for one

Comment: How are you closing notifications belonging to other Apps?